# [ScriptHelper.RegisterClientScriptFile]: The script was registered too soon, no page form nor header was found

Tags: kentico

I am getting the above error in the Pages application on the Design tab of my page.  I am using a Portal + ASPX template. Kentico 8.2

I have this in my Master Page:

`

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcManagers" runat="server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="manScript" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ScriptMode="Release" />
<cms:CMSPortalManager ID="manPortal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

`

And I have this in my aspx template page:

`

```
<cms:CMSPagePlaceholder ID="plcZone" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
<cms:CMSWebPartZone ZoneId="WebParts" runat="server" />
</LayoutTemplate>
</cms:CMSPagePlaceholder>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The fixed ended up being to convert the head tag to a .net control.

```
<head ruant="server" id="MainHeadTag">
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes it but I find myself asking why this makes any sense...